# Rewrite rules for multilingual website using Wordpress

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

[enter link description here](https://localizejs.com)I know very little about .htaccess and I need an advice.

I'm developing a multilingual website with Wordpress and I will translate the content using some JS magic called [Localise.js](https://localizejs.com)

With this web app I can translate easily any URL by adding the parameter `?ljs=XX` to my url.

So for instance if I want to translate this url http://www.example.com/company into Spanish I will use the url http://www.example.com/company?ljs=es

For SEO purpose, I would like to rewrite the URL into something more meaningful like :
http://www.example.com/es/company

So page like :

http://www.example.com/es/company

http://www.example.com/fr/company

http://www.example.com/jp/company

are just pointing to http://www.example.com/company

How could I merge these rules with Wordpress basic rewrite rules?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried to tweak [that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19644464/345901) but without any luck.

Thanks in advance for your time and patience.

Peace.

Comment: do you happen to have mod_proxy loaded and enabled?

Comment: Yes I do have mod_proxy enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will do it for you, there may be a wordpress specific way to handle this using its internal rewrite engine, but with mod_proxy enabled, you can try internally proxying the request to wordpress. The reason for this is because this creates a *new* request that wordpress would be able to interpret. Otherwise, when you internally rewrite, server variables like `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` would be wrong.

So something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|es|fr|jp)/(.*)$ /$2?ijs=$1 [L,QSA,P]
```

And you'd need to either fill out the `(en|es|fr|jp)` list to include all the languages you support, or change that regex to `([a-z]{2})`. Then you'd add that rule right below `RewriteBase /`.

Comment: Hi Jon. This works perfectly but I think I will need to use Wordpress rewrite rule system to achieve my goal. With your solution, everything works great until I change page with internal link the language code is just removed by Wordpress (which is not aware of the rule).